# How can I support PEX coming through the floor

Tags: plumbing

I have a PEX water line feeding my fridge. There is a Shark Bite style fitting valve just above where the PEX comes through the floor. I had a bracket there to try to support the PEX, but the plastic bracket broke. Is there a proper way to support the PEX?

I know, a proper way would be to support it from underneath. Unfortunately, that area is inaccessible.

[image: View of fitting]

Answer (score 0):

I would take a brass fitting and solder (silver solder) a bracket to that then add the fitting between the pex fitting and the isolation valve.

Answer (score 0):

The pipe should be fastened to the floor so it doesn't act as a load-bearing support for the valve.

You could use a plate like this one, the pipe screws in the back via a PEX fitting:

[image]

... but that would require enlarging the hole, which would be inconvenient while the pipe is in there.

The usual way is to fasten this to your wall:

[image]

Then screw in a quarter-turn 90° valve like this:

[image]

That holds the pipe so it won't get smashed while cleaning the floor.

([photo](https://www.manomano.fr/p/applique-traversee-de-cloison-d16-femelle-15x21-laiton-brut-1152936) [credits](https://www.toolstation.fr/applique-machine-a-laver/p31653?channable=00388969640033313635337f&utm_id=go_cmp-14598528845_adg-124879842617_ad-544729824903_pla-1440119789737_dev-c_ext-_prd-31653_mca-101179829_sig-CjwKCAiAwKyNBhBfEiwA_mrUMsP7pq5mR3SZcX0A9SACFOVTWE8mgwlnqDjgtMjf5ZU29-2gme1aXhoCqVAQAvD_BwE&utm_source=google))